# How to show Alertdialog or windows pop up when device screen off?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alertdialog, popupwindow

I want to show Alertdialog or windows pop up when device screen off  like a picture.
Could you please give an advice?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I trying to search solution many long time ,Now i found it as below code, it works.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
//builder.setView(R.layout.popup_activity);
builder.setTitle("Test alertdialog");
builder.setMessage("your message for show alert!!");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.tanksmall_2);
builder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("View", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });

AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

dialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount=1.0f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

I hope help someone who need like me, thanks